# Range element heating issue

Tags: appliances, glass-top-range

My LG LRE6385ST radiant Electric range's left front element doesn't heat-up properly.  When using in smaller/single mode, it heats up then it cools down and never heats back up as it   used to before.

I did reset the power and tried this element in double/full mode and it works fine;  heats up, turn off then back on to maintain the temperature, No problem there.

Now   it has started to work OK again,   my question is:

Is the element dying and needs to be replaced?   OR  Are the control board parts are in their last stages?

Comment: We can not do any diagnostics from here. Perhaps an appliance technician will be able to physically diagnose it. Perhaps contacting the manufacturer or searching an appliance repair forum will shed some light on whether or not it is a known problem.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: Additional information:  when I tried to turn on the rear left small elements, it turns on both rear and front single/smaller element of the same side as well.  The front turns off when i turn off the rear as well.  But when i turn on smaller/single left front, it doesn't turn on the rear, it acts normal.   It seems to me that there is an issue in the control board or one of the board(s) instead of the elements.  Any suggestion which board or perhaps the model of the board that is the issue. Thanks